# "Type 'EventEmitter' is not generic" ERROR in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently following a tutorial and the tutorial is making use of `EventEmitter`. The code goes like this

```
@Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> =
        new EventEmitter<string>();
```

But it visual studio code gives me these errors:

1. Type 'EventEmitter' is not generic.
2. Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

Even in the [angular website](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) it looks like that code is correct.

I'm currently using Angular CLI: 1.7.4; Node: 8.11.1; Typescript: 2.8.1

Answer (score 398, accepted):

You are probably using the `node` native EventEmitter from `node/index.d.ts` i.e.

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

## Fix

Change the import to the one from angular:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 17):

For me, VS code IDE V1.60.0 has added automatically this code:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'stream';
```

However, it is wrong and you should replace it with this

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 3):

I was doing the same tutorial and faced the same issue.

It is a problem with an import. `EventEmitter` must be  imported from `@angular/core`

Use:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

This will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

**This is the latest update for Angular 13**

This is happening because the `EventEmitter` might be imported from the `events` module.

```
import * as EventEmitter from 'events';
```

Or

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

**To fix this**, import `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core`

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code when your try to listen to user click event from your html file of the component

`@Output() event: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();`

it automatically import this to the component `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/event'` instead of `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'`.

Resource: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2