# Angular 8 @output EventEmitter not letting an Object to be emitted

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How would I emit an Object instead of primitive data types?

I have a object `const amount = { currenty: 'USD', total: '10.25' };` 
which I wanted to emmit to the parent component.

```
export class MyChildComponent implements OnInit {
     @Output() childEventEmitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
....
}
```

in the emitter function

`this.childEventEmitter.emit(amount);` // not working

error: Argument of type { currenty: 'USD', total: '10.25' } not assignable to paraments of type string

Comment: Can you add the Parent Component Code? Please, add the .html and .ts codes.

Answer (score 6):

I am answering my own question after I found this solution ["Type 'EventEmitter' is not generic" ERROR in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911879/type-eventemitter-is-not-generic-error-in-angular)

The issue was I was importing EventEmitter from Protractor instead of @angular/core;
Thank you for all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Output() childEventEmitter: EventEmitter<{currenty: string, total: string}> = new EventEmitter<{currenty: string, total: string}>();
```

Comment: The typing isn’t needed here. It’s inferred from initialization

Comment: You mean like this `@Output() childEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<{currenty: string, total: string}>();`

Comment: Yes. The type declaration is just extra. Just need to type the emitter

Answer (score 0):

That's because Typescript is complaining of incompatible types.
Either use

```
@Output() childEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<{currenty: string, total: string}>();
```

or

```
@Output() childEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way by passing any kind of parameter through the event.

```
@Output() childEventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting here my scenario, just in case someone may hit the same issue.

My problem was similar to this but instead I was trying to call `Output` callback directly from HTML, like this:

##### Child Component

```js
...
 @Output() isCategorySelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

##### Child Component HTML

```html
 <option *ngFor="let category of todoCategories" [value]="category"
                    [selected]="isCategorySelected(category)">{{category}}
                </option>
```

##### Parent Component HTML

```html
<app-child (isCategorySelected)="myCategorySelectorFunc($event)"></app-child>
```

---

#### Solution

As you might see the issue is that int the Child component I had to have another method in the component and call the output from it, like this:

```js
...
 @Output() isCategorySelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

 public onCategorySelected(category: string): void {
    this.isCategorySelected.next(category);
 }
```

##### Child Component HTML

```html
 <option *ngFor="let category of todoCategories" [value]="category"
                    [selected]="onCategorySelected(category)">{{category}}
                </option>
```

**OR**

```html
 <option *ngFor="let category of todoCategories" [value]="category"
                    [selected]="isCategorySelected.next(category)">{{category}}
                </option>
```

---

### Conclusion

Remember that EventEmitter, BehaviorSubject, Subject can't be called directly as methods from HTML.